# jQuery add required to input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have been searching ways to have jQuery automatically write required using html5 validation to my all of my input fields but I am having trouble telling it where to write it.

I want to take this

```
 <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" id="freeform_first_name"
 maxlength="150">
```

and have it automatically add **required** before the closing tag

```
 <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" id="freeform_first_name"
 maxlength="150" required>
```

I thought I  could do someting along the lines of

```
$("input").attr("required", "true");
```

But it doesn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it not wrapped in dom ready? `$(function(){....});`

Comment: I am using this http://jsfiddle.net/japaneselanguagefriend/LEZ4r/

Comment: if 'input' is an id the jquery is missing the # in the selector here.

Comment: @JohnMeyer "input" is a tag selector. No # needed if targeting input tags

Answer (score 556, accepted):

```
$("input").prop('required',true);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LEZ4r/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Hmm, added a submit button but still not validating or adding the required attribute to the input fields.
http://jsfiddle.net/japaneselanguagefriend/LEZ4r/

Comment: @JohnMeyer "input" is a tag selector

Comment: got a `TypeError: element.prop is not a function` error

Comment: @Miura-shi You're missing the `<form></form>` tags in your jsFiddle

Comment: If it can help someone : this wasn't working for me at first because I was calling `.prop('required',true)` on the input *before* calling `.css("display", "block")` on it.

Answer (score 71):

You can do it by using attr, the mistake that you made is that you put the true inside quotes.  instead of that try this:

```
$("input").attr("required", true);
```

Comment: @JohnMeyer "input" is the name of a tag selector

Comment: `required` is a _boolean_ attribute and should only ever be omitted (for "false"), or have the same value as its name (i.e. `"required"`) for "true".   It's actually better to use `.prop()`.

Comment: @Alnitak Not if you're working on making a site compatible with IE, `prop()` doesn't work on there as it does on modern browsers. Still best to use `$(ele).attr("required", true)` and `false` to remove.

Answer (score 46):

I have found that the following implementations are effective:

```
$('#freeform_first_name').removeAttr('required');

$('#freeform_first_name').attr('required', 'required');
```

These commands (attr, removeAttr, prop) behave differently depending on the version of JQuery you are using. Please reference the documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 20):

Using `.attr` method

```js
// syntax
.attr(attribute,value);

.attr("required", true);
// output: required="required"

.attr("required", false);
// output:
```

Using `.prop`

```js
// syntax
.prop(property,value)

.prop("required", true);
// output: required=""

.prop("required", false);
// output:
```

Read more from here

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/5413283

Answer (score 8):

Should not enclose **true** with **double quote** " " it should be like

```
$(document).ready(function() {            
   $('input').attr('required', true);   
});
```

Also you can use prop

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {            
   $('input').prop('required', true);   
});
```

Instead of **true** you can try required. Such as

```
$('input').prop('required', 'required');
```

Answer (score 6):

I found that jquery 1.11.1 does not do this reliably.

I used `$('#estimate').attr('required', true)` and `$('#estimate').removeAttr('required')`.

Removing `required` was not reliable. It would sometimes leave the `required` attribute without value. Since `required` is a boolean attibute, its mere presence, without value, is seen by the browser as `true`.

This bug was intermittent, and I got tired of messing with it. Switched to `document.getElementById("estimate").required = true` and `document.getElementById("estimate").required = false`.

Comment: `removeAttr` doesn't work to me. Then I use your solution and works fine. Thanks!