# How to add required on different form when button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to add `required` on different form, before execute button?

let say I have a HTML code when I used this code in JS:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#button1').click(function() {
    $("#email").prop('required', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*">
</form>
<form>
  <button id="button1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

the button keep execute even the `textfield` of email is null,

expected result: need to show this text if input field is null when click the button

[image: required]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9wbranL3/)

Answer (score 1):

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/andreitodorut/xe3z0nas/

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" id="email_to" name="email_to" required="required" placeholder="Email*">
  <button class="hide submit-form">
  Submit
  </button>
</form>
<form data-submit="#form1">
  <button id="button1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form[data-submit]').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var formToSubmit = $(this).attr('data-submit');

    if(formToSubmit){
        $(formToSubmit).find('.submit-form').trigger('click');
    }
  })
})
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide {
    display: none; 
}
```

**UPDATE**
https://jsfiddle.net/9wbranL3/4/

Comment: would be hard if I have more than1 input textfield, :(

Comment: what would be hard ? You can't modify the first form ?

Comment: actually I've 6 inputfield and 1 button for each form tag, so I cant modify your code for all of my inputfield, it's gonna be to long,

Comment: could you give me the whole html in a `jsfiddle` please ?

Comment: this is the whole inputfield required i've create https://jsfiddle.net/9wbranL3/1/

Comment: that code just work if email field is null, not for each null input textfield

Comment: you talk about required fields ?

Comment: sure, I'm asking about required **each** inputfield

Comment: but you have to set the required attribute to each field you want to be required

Comment: sure, my bad, I didn't see you add required at email form only

Comment: sure, but i like to add required for each form like this https://jsfiddle.net/9wbranL3/4/ xD, thanks for the code sir

Answer (score 1):

You just had to put everything in the same form.

As you can see, now that i've commented the separator, it works ^^

```js
$(function() {
  $('#button1').click(function() {
    $("#email").prop('required', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*">
<!--</form>
<form>-->
  <button id="button1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: same as Code Lღver comment : I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166685/jquery-add-required-to-input-fields), and its showing what you say, but **I need to seperate form tag** for each input and button

Comment: No you don't, trust me ^^

PS: It isn't the same comment, he added a useless attribute to the input

Comment: my input field with [separate form tag](https://pasteboard.co/H4nJOMX.png), and my input field in [1 form tag](https://pasteboard.co/H4nJsb1.png)

Comment: I'm just modify the code that already created, so I won't learn css, and I'm not front-end dev xD

Comment: I'm not a frontend developer too, but if you think that you can use different forms, it means that you aren't a backend developer, cause you didn't understand how does this aarchitecture works

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the button inside the same form tag.

**HTML:**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*">

  <button id="button1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And the add the require attribute to email field, code is below:

```
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*" required="true">
```

When you will submit the form it will check the blank condition and will show the same message are showing in the image.

Comment: I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166685/jquery-add-required-to-input-fields), and its showing what you say, but I need to seperate form tag for each input and button