# Form input attributes based on other inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Below I have been trying to get the `eoddesc` field to be `required` depending on whether the `completetasks` value is `Yes` or `No`. I made a quick script which executes upon click of the submit button. As of now, it can remove the `required` property from the `eoddesc` input, but if the value is changed back to `Yes`, then it stays without a `required` attribute.

```
<form action="/addeod" method="POST" id="addEODForm">
    <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8 mt-4">
                    <label for="completetasks">Did I complete all my tasks that were due today and/or overdue?</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 mb-3">
                    <select class="browser-default custom-select" id="completetasks" name="success" style="margin-top: 30px;" required>
                        <option value="" selected>Yes/No:</option>
                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <textarea id="eoddesc" class="form-control md-textarea" name="ifno" length="120" rows="3" required></textarea>
                        <label for="eoddesc">If not, please explain why:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <textarea id="eodsum" class="form-control md-textarea" name="summary" length="120" rows="3" required></textarea>
                        <label for="eodsum">Briefly summarize all you've completed today:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer d-block">
            <div class="row w-100">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-12 "><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect w-100" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a></div>
                <div id="eodSumButton" class="col-sm-6 col-12"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light w-100">Submit</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#eodSumButton").click(function () {
        if ($("#completetasks").val() == "Yes"){
            console.log("NOT required");
            $("#eoddesc").removeAttr("required");
        }
        if ($("#completetasks").val() == "No"){
            console.log("required");
            $("#eoddesc").attr("required");
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Why does the form not update with the `required` field? When I console.log it, everything outputs as expected, but it does not want to update the `attr`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery add required to input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166685/jquery-add-required-to-input-fields)

Comment: My question is different, I know the jquery method to use to add and remove attributes, I am asking why it is that it is not working.

Comment: You either need to use `$("#eoddesc").attr('required', true);` or `$("#eoddesc").prop('required',true);`. Just `$("#eoddesc").attr("required");` will not work.

Comment: Unrelated from your question, but just as an FYI about bootstrap - having a `row` with a `col-12` is 100% wide, so it's actually  to not having these classes at all.  they are both look the same, so you might as well remove them to simplify your code.  `<p>hello</p>` looks the same as `<div class="row"><div class="col-12"><p>hello</p></div></div>`

Comment: @ChrisBarr oh thanks, that is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the event listener for your `completetasks` input instead of `eodSumButton`. Otherwise the code only checks that when you try to submit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#completetasks").on('change',function () {
        if ($("#completetasks").val() == "Yes"){
            console.log("NOT required");
            $("#eoddesc").removeAttr("required");
        }
        if ($("#completetasks").val() == "No"){
            console.log("required");
            $("#eoddesc").attr("required");
        }
   })
});
```

The problem is that the "required" is evaluated before the submit. So when you press submit, it sees the field as "not required" and then it adds the attribute required.

**EDIT:**
I think I figured out your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#completetasks").click(function () {
        if ($("#completetasks").val() == "Yes"){
            $("#output").html("NOT required");
            $("#eoddesc").removeAttr("required");
        }
        if ($("#completetasks").val() == "No"){
             $("#output").html("required");
            $("#eoddesc").prop("required",true);
        }
    })
});
```

<strike>When using "attributes" like `required` and `checked`, Jquery considers them a `property`, so to add "required" use `.prop`. But to remove, you still use `removeAttr`.
I hope this fixes your problem.</strike>

Fixed, the comment of  Bharat Geleda  is the true correct answer.

Comment: Actually the `eodSumButton.click(function () {` is different from the submit. My submit script looks like `$(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#addEODForm").submit(function (e) {`. I have a AJAX function for the submission. Because of this, your solution also does not work.

Comment: Ok, see my edit. I think this should fix it. I've kept, the on("change") because I think it would be better to change this when you change the "select", but you can probably revert it back to what you had.