# I can't add the required attribute to a select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML `<select>` tag and I want to make it dynamically required. I tried with jQuery but nothing happens.

This is the `<select>`

```html
<select class="form-control" type="text" id="status">
  <option value="" selected disabled>----- * ----</option>
  <option value="1" >inactive</option>
  <option value="2" >active</option>
</select>
```

I tried with JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById("status").required = true
```

and then with jQuery:

```js
$('select[id=status]').prop('required', true);

$('#status').attr('required');
```

But none of those worked, no error, nothing.

Edit: this problem is specific to `<select>`. With `<input>` it works fine.

Comment: `.attr('required', true)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166685/jquery-add-required-to-input-fields

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery add required to input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166685/jquery-add-required-to-input-fields)

Comment: @natel - please vote to close as duplicate (as I did)

Comment: @natel with `<input>`  works fine my problem is with `<select>` I checked with chrome and the attribute is not added

Comment: Your first try works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/x12978ne/2

Answer (score 0):

How to handle attributes...

```
Input_ID.setAttribute('required',''); // SET the attribute


if(Input_ID.hasAttribute('required')){}  // TEST if the attribute exists


R=Input_ID.getAttribute('required'); // GET the value of the attribute


Input_ID.removeAttribute('required') // REMOVE the attribute
```

Given all the above options you should be able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS you can use [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) with an empty string as the value to add the `required` tag:

```
document
  .getElementById("status")
  .setAttribute("required", "")
```