# An invalid form control with name='AdjustmentBuyerPrice' is not focusable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

Below is the HTML and the JavaScript being used to display the dropdown only if one of the options from the preceding dropdown is selected. When I select the one that is linked the following dropdown it works while when I select the second option not linked to the following dropdown and click submit, it throws the error "An invalid form control with name='AdjustmentBuyerPrice' is not focusable". Please point out the mistake that I did in my code.

```
`{include file="header.tpl" page_name='Amazon Order Adjustment' extra_javascript='<script language="JavaScript" src="includes/update_shipping_info.js"></script>'}

{literal}
<style type="text/css">
#loading-icon {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 75px; 
    right: 250px; width: 
    32px; height: 32px;
    display: none; 
    background: url('/images/lightbox/loading.gif');
}
</style>
{/literal}

{if isset($tpl_error_msg) }
    <div id="message">{$tpl_error_msg}</div>
{/if}

{include file='view_order_snippet.tpl'}

<form name="amazon_order_adjustment" id="amazon_order_adjustment" method="post" action="amazon_order_adjustment.php?id={$id}&{$search_params}">
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Order Line Items</legend>
                <table id="table2" style="position: relative; float: left;">
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <th width="10%"></th>
                        <th width="10%">SKU</th>
                        <th width="30%">Item</th>
                        <th width="5%">Qty</th>
                        <th width="10%">Status</th>
                        <th width="15%">Ship Mode</th>
                        <th width="20%">Tracking#</th>
                    </tr>
                    {if !($update_shipping_info_flag)}
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7" align="center">No Items to display</td>
                        </tr>
                    {else}
                        {section name=lineitems loop=$tpl_order_list}
                            <tr id=row1 valign="top">
                                <td><input type="radio" name="check[]" value="{$tpl_order_list[lineitems].id}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="vendor_id_array[]" value="{$tpl_order_list[lineitems].vendor_fk}">
                                </td>
                                <td>{$tpl_order_list[lineitems].sku}
                                <td>{$tpl_order_list[lineitems].item_description}</td>
                                <td>{$tpl_order_list[lineitems].quantity}</td>
                                <td>{$tpl_order_list[lineitems].item_status}</td>
                                <td>{$tpl_order_list[lineitems].shipping_mode}</td>
                                {if $tpl_order_list[lineitems].shipping_tracking_no == ""}
                                <td>N/A</td>
                                {else}
                                <td>{$tpl_order_list[lineitems].shipping_tracking_no}</td>
                                {/if}
                            </tr>
                        {/section}
                    {/if}
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" colspan="3">Action Type</td>
                        <td align="left" colspan="4">
                            <select id="action_type" name="action_type" required>   
                                <option value="">Select Action</option>
                                {html_options options=$tpl_action_type}
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" colspan="3">Enter Refund Amount</td>
                        <td align="left" colspan="4"><input type="number" step="1" min="" id="refund_amount" name="refund_amount" value="" required /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" colspan="3">Adjustment Reason</td>
                        <td align="left" colspan="4">
                            <select id="AdjustmentReason" name="AdjustmentReason" required> 
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Adjustment Reason</option>
                                {html_options options=$tpl_adjustment_reason}                           
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" colspan="3">Adjustment Type</td>
                        <td align="left" colspan="4">
                            <select id="adjustment_type" name="adjustment_type" required>   
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Select Adjustment Type</option>
                                {html_options options=$tpl_adjustment_type}                             
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="adjustment_buyer_price">
                        <td align="right" colspan="3">Adjustment Buyer Price Type</td>
                        <td align="left" colspan="4">
                            <select id="AdjustmentBuyerPrice" name="AdjustmentBuyerPrice" required> 
                                <option value="">Select Adjustment Buyer Price Type</option>
                                {html_options options=$tpl_adjustment_buyer_price}
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="hidden" id="tpl_grand_total_box" name="tpl_grand_total_box" value="{$tpl_grand_total}">
            <input type="hidden" id="tpl_tax_box" name="tpl_tax_box" value="{$tpl_tax}">
            <input type="submit" id="save_button" name="submit_action" value="refund" class="button">
            <input type="submit" id="cancel_button" name="cancel_action" value="Cancel" class="button">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#adjustment_buyer_price').hide(); 
        $("#adjustment_type").change(function () {
            var cur_option_val = $(this).val(); 
            if (cur_option_val == "ItemPriceAdjustments") {
                $('#adjustment_buyer_price').show(); 
                $('#AdjustmentBuyerPrice').attr("required", "required") //add required
            } else {
                $('#adjustment_buyer_price').hide();
                $('#AdjustmentBuyerPrice').removeAttr("required") //remove required.
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
{/literal}
{include file="footer.tpl"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have `AdjustmentBuyerPrice` as `required` so when you have not selected value `ItemPriceAdjustments` its hidden and when you click on submit button that error shows .Instead you can remove `required` attribute when that select box is hidden else add required attribute .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#adjustment_buyer_price').hide();
  $("#adjustment_type").change(function() {
    var cur_option_val = $(this).val();
    if (cur_option_val == "ItemPriceAdjustments") {
      $('#adjustment_buyer_price').show();
      $('#AdjustmentBuyerPrice').attr("required", "required") //add required
    } else {
      $('#adjustment_buyer_price').hide();
      $('#AdjustmentBuyerPrice').removeAttr("required") //remove
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="amazon_order_adjustment" id="amazon_order_adjustment" method="post" action="amazon_order_adjustment.php?id={$id}&{$search_params}">
  <div class="row">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Order Line Items</legend>
      <table id="table2" style="position: relative; float: left;">
        <tr valign="top">
          <th width="10%"></th>
          <th width="10%">SKU</th>
          <th width="30%">Item</th>
          <th width="5%">Qty</th>
          <th width="10%">Status</th>
          <th width="15%">Ship Mode</th>
          <th width="20%">Tracking#</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="7" align="center">No Items to display</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id=row1 valign="top">
          <td><input type="radio" name="check[]" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="vendor_id_array[]" value="2">
          </td>
          <td>A
            <td>B</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>ok</td>
            <td>htm</td>
            <td>N/A</td>


        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td align="right" colspan="3">Action Type</td>
          <td align="left" colspan="4">
            <select id="action_type" name="action_type" required>
              <option value="">Select Action</option>
              <option value="">A</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" colspan="3">Enter Refund Amount</td>
          <td align="left" colspan="4"><input type="number" step="1" min="" id="refund_amount" name="refund_amount" value="" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" colspan="3">Adjustment Reason</td>
          <td align="left" colspan="4">
            <select id="AdjustmentReason" name="AdjustmentReason" required>
              <option value="" selected="selected">Select Adjustment Reason</option>
              <option value="">A</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" colspan="3">Adjustment Type</td>
          <td align="left" colspan="4">
            <select id="adjustment_type" name="adjustment_type" required>
              <option value="" selected="selected">Select Adjustment Type</option>
              <option value="ItemPriceAdjustments">ItemPriceAdjustments</option>
              <option value="ItemPriceAdjustments1">5</option>

            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="adjustment_buyer_price">
          <td align="right" colspan="3">Adjustment Buyer Price Type</td>
          <td align="left" colspan="4">
            <!--remove required from here-->
            <select id="AdjustmentBuyerPrice" name="AdjustmentBuyerPrice">
              <option value="">Select Adjustment Buyer Price Type</option>
              <option value="">A</option>

            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="save_button" name="submit_action" value="refund" class="button">

</form>
```

Comment: Why is required twice in this line `$('#AdjustmentBuyerPrice').attr("required", "required") //add required`

Comment: you need `attributename` and `value` to set in attr so `required` is `attributename` and `required` is `value` and it will show like this : `required=required`. There are other way also to set attr check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166685/jquery-add-required-to-input-fields) out .

Comment: When clicking the cancel button now, I get the same console error `An invalid form control with name='AdjustmentBuyerPrice' is not focusable`. Let me past the full code now for you to have a look at.

Comment: because your `name='AdjustmentBuyerPrice'` has `required` attribute by default remove that from html as well.

Comment: Removed the attribute. Now Cancel button works only if I select every dropdown, otherwise it doesn't work. It throws required field error message.

Comment: why you have `type="submit"` for reset button as well?

Comment: To redirect the page in the PHP script if the submit value is "Cancel" Am I doing anything wrong with Cancel button here? Please advice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229132/discussion-between-swati-and-codeforgood).